# Compare dictionary values and key in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary `item`. It has strings as keys and the values are lists e.g.:

```
item['title'] = [u'python']
item['image'] = [u'/link/to/image']
item['link'] = [u'link to article']
```

I want to check if any value is 0 in length, but link or image may be empty, so I did the following:

```
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            if len(value) == 0:
                if key != 'image' or key != 'link':
                    raise DropItem("Item is empty: %s" %item)                   
        return item
```

So an item should be dropped only if the value is 0 and it is not an image or a key. My problem is now that this condition does not work. The item is still dropped when the image or link is empty.

Any idea whats wrong? (I am new to python^^)

Comment: Note that the idiom for checking for an empty collection (list, dict, set, string, etc.) is `if not xs:` (and conversely, checking whether it's nonempty is `if xs:`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You confused the logical `or` with `and`. For example, if the key is `"image"`, you check the following:

```
if "image" != 'image' or "image" != 'link':
#if      False        or        True:
#if True:
```

Instead, you want

```
if key != 'image' and key != 'link':
```

or, easier to read:

```
if key not in ('image', 'link'):
```

Answer (score 4):

You should :

```
if key != 'image' and key != 'link':
```

because

```
 if key != 'image' or key != 'link':
```

is always true